# move elements common between two column in other column

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

after make a check common elements,

COLUMN A : 1, 2, 3, 6, 5
COLUMN B : 7 , 6 ,1 ,8 ,2

Result :
COLUMN C : 1, 2,6

and in COLUMN A : 3 , 5 that they up of the row ( number in common with column B move definitly in column C )

really thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var col1 = new Array().concat(...sh.getRange("A1:A5").getValues());
  var col2 = new Array().concat(...sh.getRange("B1:B5").getValues());
  //get similar elements in column A and column B 
  var similar = col1.filter(element => col2.indexOf(element) !== -1);
  //remove similar to column A
  var new_col1 = col1.filter(a => !similar.includes(a));
  //clear Col A data
  sh.getRange(1,1,col1.length, 1).clear();
  //set Col C data
  sh.getRange(1,3,similar.length, 1).setValues(array1dto2d(similar));
  //set Col A data
  sh.getRange(1,1,new_col1.length, 1).setValues(array1dto2d(new_col1));
}

function array1dto2d(arr){
  var c = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    c.push([arr[i]]);
  }
  return c;
}
```

Example:

[image: 1]

Output:

[image]

### References:

1. [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
2. [Array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)
3. [Range.setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: good! thankyou , than after i found the same numbers , iwould like that in Column A delete , so 1, 2, 6 there are no more in column A, in practice they move from column A to column C (not copy)  and in column A they remain  3, 5 
which are the numbers that are not in common

Comment: hi Nikko , if i would like move other elements besides 1, 2, 6 , so example 3 colums , not only 1,2,6 (common elemets) but  1 , sugar , 3    /    2 , tomatos , 24     /    6 , hamburger 1  , than are 3 colums   , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply
convert column A to a string

```
let columnA = [1, 2, 3, 6, 5];
let columnB = [7 , 6 ,1 ,8 ,2];
columnA = columnA.join('-');
let C = '';
let index = null;
for(let i = 0, j = columnB.length; i < j; i++) {
  index = columnA.indexOf(columnB[i]);
  if(index > -1) {
   C += columnA.substr(index, 1) + ',';
  }
}
```

You need to take care of these things though -
Only single digits are allowed.